# how to feed multi-array data to a model?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

As you can see below the object `n3w_coin` has a method called `forecast_coin()` which returns a data frame that has 5 columns after removing date_time , i split the data with `train_test_split` and then normalize it with `sc` , after converting the 2D array to a 3D array that i would like to pass to the model to train on but i am having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to feed the `normalized_x_train` to the model

my goal is to feed every sub-array inside `normalized_x_train` to the model

I get the following error
`IndexError: tuple index out of range`

please explain why and what is wrong with my approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame(n3w_coin.forecast_coin())

x_sth = np.array(df.drop(['date_time'],1))
y_sth = np.array(df.drop(['date_time'],1))



sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_sth,y_sth, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)

print (X_train)
normalized_x_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
normalized_y_train = sc.fit_transform(y_train)

print (normalized_x_train)

### converting to a 3D array to feed the model 

normalized_x_train = np.reshape(normalized_x_train, (400 , 5 ,1 ))

print (normalized_x_train.shape)

print (normalized_x_train)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units = 100, return_sequences = True, input_shape=(normalized_x_train.shape[5],1)))
 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(normalized_x_train, normalized_y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=400 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of observations from your code:

1. In addition to **`Normalizing the Data`**, you need to **`Prepare`** the **`Time Series Data`**. Please find the `function` below, which `pre-processes` the `Data` so that it can be fed to `LSTM Model`.

```
def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []

  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])

    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)
```

The `parameters`, `history_size` and `target_size` are important. `history_size` indicates how many values in the `Time Series` needs to be considered for `predicting` the `Target Value`. `target_size` indicates which `Future Value` exactly needs to be predicted.

2. Your `Network` has only 1 `LSTM Layer` and you are setting the value of the argument, `return_sequences = True`. Value of that parameter should be **`True`** only if there is another `LSTM Layer` after this `Layer`.
3. Since you want to predict a Numeric Value, there should be a Dense Layer at the end with `1 Neuron/Unit/Node`, and with `Activation = 'linear'`.

Please refer this [Tensorflow Tutorial on Time Series Analysis](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series#part_2_forecast_a_multivariate_time_series) which comprises complete code for your problem.